# how to split and retain the splitting criteria in perl

Tags: regex, perl

suppose i have a string like the following

`mother-in-law` , I need the output to have 5 tokens like `mother` , `-` , `in` , `-` , `law` .

I tried splitting based on hyphen , but I could only get three tokens `mother` ,  `in` `law` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the split regex contains capturing groups, then the contents of each capturing group will be returned by `split`. So to keep your `-` delimiters, just write

```
split /(-)/, "mother-in-law"
```

instead of

```
split /-/, "mother-in-law"
```

Comment: So we need to have `( )` to retain delimiters too ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `/(-)/` as split pattern:

```
print join(' ', split(/(-)/, 'mother-in-law'));
```

prints

```
mother - in - law
```

According to [split - perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

> If the PATTERN contains capturing groups, then for each separator, an
>   additional field is produced for each substring captured by a group